# using more than 8 temperature probe of DS18B20 on Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide

I am trying to use more than 8 temperature DS18b20 on one bus. Is there any problem to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see there is no limit on the number of sensors you can have on a bus.

So if you are having problems does your code work with less sensors? Try one and work up.

Is it a current issue are you pulling to much from the board?

Is the problem with the one wire library?

Have you got 4.7k pull ups on each sensor?

Comment: Is it possible that sharing the VCC is causing interference between the probes data lines do you need diodes after the resistors?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you connect each sensor on a different pin, you should be able to collect the data without any problems.

Otherwise try to search for a I2C temperature sensor and use a demux to control 8 sensors.

Comment: DS18b20 uses OneWire, so you can have multiple on the same bus/pin.

Comment: It depends on the different address, so he is better of to use an individual pin each time

Comment: Each device has a unique 64-bit address. I don't think they made eighteen quintillion units yet, so they don't to have to reuse addresses.